# Magento method "removeTab" doesn't work

Tags: php, magento

I made an observer that triggers on event `adminhtml_block_html_before`, but when i try to remove tab nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
public function alterMenu($observer) {
    $block = $observer->getBlock();     
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tabs)
        $block->removeTab('order_rma');
    }
```

After, if I use `print_r($block->getTabsIds());` there is the following situation:

```
Array
(
    [0] => order_info
    [1] => order_invoices
    [2] => order_creditmemos
    [3] => order_shipments
    [4] => order_history
    [5] => order_transactions
)
```

But the tab is still visible. I'm using Magento EE 1.12. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your observer is setup correctly and grabbing the block after the tabs are added?

Comment: yes because if i do:

    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View)
        $block->removeButton('create_rma');

the button is removed correctly.

Comment: It's probably being added by a module after this event has been triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` instead of `adminhtml_block_html_before`, probably with this event the tab is removed before is rendered.